# Android Parse - Fetch parse objects for list of object ids

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have an ArrayList of userIds and I want to fetch every user where userId is in that ArrayList. I don't want to use for loop and to make request for every userId in the list. Is there an option to send ArrayList as a parameter and to get list of ParseObjects as a response?

Comment: what do u mean by not using a for loop?

Comment: and from where do you want to fetch users? from a backend server? from your local db?

Comment: I want to fetch users from a backend server

Comment: @HariKrishnan What I can do is to make request for every id that I have in the list by using for loop, but for sure there is a better way how to do this

Comment: cant u send a json which have all these ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    List<String> userIds = new ArrayList<>();
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> userParseQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
    userParseQuery.whereContainedIn("objectId", userIds);
    userParseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){
                //  
            } else {
                // 
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a contains() method you can use if I even understand you properly.
It's been a while since I did something like that but i think it has to be overridden. for example if you have ArrayList you can override the method to take an object of person as a parameter and compare a few fields of the person object then return a boolean or something like that. bus since you don't want to use a for loop then I guess you will just have to use a for-each loop then